# A little issue that use Facebook JavaScript SDK in Metro Mode of Windows 8 with JavaScript based application

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, windows-8

I use Facebook JavaScript SDK in Metro Mode of Windows 8 with JavaScript based application.

First, I use iframe to load facebook.html file in default.html with

```
<iframe id="facebookIframe" src="ms-wwa-web:///facebook.html"></iframe>
```

and add

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

in facebook.html file.
(According to [Load remote .js file into app](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winappswithhtml5/thread/3532cbad-7d5e-4a28-8e73-6b562a4dfa04) )

When application running, JavaScript Console said

```
* Windows Web Applications supports a limited set of ActiveX controls.
* JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined. File: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js, line: 7 column: 1313
```

Then I download all.js from Facebook and add it into Visual Studio project.

Load it by

```
<script src="/js/all.js"></script>
```

And modify the part of error occur in all.js from

```
if(navigator.mimeTypes.length>0)
```

to

```
if(navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes.length>0)
```

And it seems to work...

Is it a bug of Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Thanks for replying in advance.

Sars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more like a bug in the Metro SDK... if they want client scripts to have a decent chance at working, navigator.mimeTypes should return an empty collection (like it does in IE10) instead of undefined.